# docker run command --publish value option ?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I wanna use docker to run a zookeeper image. The instruction command is

```
docker run -d -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 --name zookeeper    confluent/zookeeper
```

I am not clear with -p option,  what does these three "-p "options mean in this zookeeper example ? and why we have two same port value in a single -p options. I would expect like  2181:localhost, not 2181:2181.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -p flag specifies which of the container you choose to expose in your container (they are all closed by default).

The purpose of using : annotation is to instruct which port of the container should be forwarded to the localhost port.
Referring to your question - mapping the port like 2181:localhost would mean nothing, because localhost is inferred automatically, but the port isn't. The reason Docker gives you the choice is because port 2181 could be occupied on your localhost, so they give you the freedom to choose a port of your choice to forward into.

Comment: Thanks. So these two ports would not have to be the same.And why we need three mapping for a zookeeper container?

Comment: I can't say specifically for zookeeper but other services often needs more than one port. Elasticsearch for example - requires 9200 for database access and 9300 for discovery purposes.